# how to merge two same value javascript object in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an object like this

```
var obj1 = {
            key1: {
                name: book1,
                count: 5
                },
            key2: {
                name: book2,
                count: 7
                },
             }

var obj2 = {
            key1: {
                name: book1,
                count: 3
                },
            key2: {
                name: book2,
                count: 5
                },
           }
```

I tried

```
var obj3 = {... obj1, ...obj2}
```

and got this result

```
var obj3 = {
            key1: {
                name: book1,
                count: 3
                },
            key2: {
                name: book2,
                count: 5
                },
           }
}
```

But I expect the result like this

```
var obj3 = {
            key1: {
                name: book1,
                count: 8
                },
            key2: {
                name: book2,
                count: 12
                },
           }
}
```

I need to merge these two objects and the count value gets added to the respective object keys
please help me to get this result thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You coullect the objects in an array and reduce by looking at the common keys.

```js
var obj1 = { key1: { name: 'book1', count: 5 }, key2: { name: 'book2', count: 7 } },
    obj2 = { key1: { name: 'book1', count: 3 }, key2: { name: 'book2', count: 5 } },
    result = [obj1, obj2].reduce((r, o) => {
        Object.entries(o).forEach(([k, v]) => {
            if (r[k]) r[k].count += v.count;
            else r[k] = { ...v };
        });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result);
```